# Recognizing domains/subdomains with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, dns, subdomain

I am creating a site for 2 companies to share. 
In development, the URL structures for both sites are:
1) xx.domain.dev
2) yy.domain.dev

Live, they will be:
1) site.xx.com
2) site.yy.com

Once a user logs into the site, sessions are set for either site depending on the user's company email address.

I would like to set those sessions earlier, though. Ideally as soon as the site is hit, depending on which domain or subdomain they are coming from, I'd set a session accordingly.

Basically, is there a way to detect the URL the site is being loaded from and set a session property accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did similar stuff and shared a codeigniter application across many sites.

I am doing something like this inside application/config/config.php :

```
$domain= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
switch($domain){
  case 'www.domain1.com' :
  case 'm.domain2.com' :
    $config['domain_name'] = 'Some domain';
    $config['country']= 'Some country';
    break;
  case 'anotherdomain.fr' :
    // ...
}
```

So I guess same thing can work for you, just ureplace with your values, and set the $_SESSION within the cases. Something like :

```
// initialize session if not already done

$domain= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
switch($domain){
  case 'xx.domain.dev' :
    $_SESSION['site']= 'xx';
    break;
  case 'yy.domain.dev' :
    $_SESSION['site']= 'yy';
    break;
}
```